# Posting to WebAPI with Angular doesn't work once published to production

Tags: angular, angular6

I am attempting to post JSON to a WebAPI with Angular 6. This works in my local environment but once I publish to Azure it no longer works. I am receiving a http 400 error and I cannot seem to figure out what the issue is.

```
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  };

  ensureUserExistsInDb(identifier: string, sesskey: string, id: number) {
    var info = { identifier: identifier, sessKey: sesskey, id: id };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(info));
    return this.http.post('/api/Survey/EnsureUserExists', JSON.stringify(info), this.httpOptions).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

WebAPI method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/survey/EnsureUserExists")]
        public void EnsureUserExists([FromBody]JToken jsonbody)
        {

        }
```

Does anyone know how I can troubleshoot this when it's in production. I am new to Angular and am struggling.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: there is no complete url. You you have an interceptor which completes the url?

Comment: I thought I could use realtive urls :(. I just updated it to be the full url but unfortunately I get the same http 400 bad request error.

Comment: What does the response of the http 400 say exactly?

Comment: Relative urls are fine. A 400 error indicates a bad request. Your endpoint is listening on the requested endpoint, but doesn't understand what you are sending it. Review the server logs and edit the stack trace into your post.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking too but I don't understand why the same code works when ran via Visual Studio but doesn't when I publish it to azure. I updated the question to include the web api method in case something jumps out.

Comment: Is there a specific reason, you're using `JToken`? If the JSON input that the webapi would consume remains fixed (`identifier`, `sessKey`,`id`), you can simply create a C# class at webapi layer which will directly get populated by ASP.NET (through model binding phase) and change your angular app to instead send data without `JSON.stringify`.  `this.http.post('/api/Survey/EnsureUserExists', info, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );`

Comment: I have tried doing that but none of the fields on the class get populated. When I post that way do I have to specify the content type as something other than application/json?